# Is there anything wrong with passing "this" as an argument to ISR registration?

Tags: c++, embedded, isr, esp-idf

I am writing a firmware for an esp32 in C++ and I found it to be awesome to pass an object reference as parameter when registering an ISR because I can simply delegate the work from the ISR to the specific object (a resource in this case), managing the resource properties and functionality directly from the class. However, I'm not exactly sure what to look out for when using this technique.

1. Is there anything inherently wrong with it?
2. If not, what should one be aware of when doing it?

Comment: How are you calling the ISR with arguments?

Comment: It's basically the same as programming in a multithreaded environment except you can't do locking. So maybe you need something like https://www.internalpointers.com/post/lock-free-multithreading-atomic-operations ?

Comment: With esp-idf, we register ISRs and also pass a void* while registering that will be used as a parameter in the ISR.

Comment: @Colin I updated the question to be more realistic and according to your comment

Comment: The small overhead caused by the additional indirection is usually no problem at all and worth it to achieve better encapsulation/modularization.
The ISR argument is obviously a comfort feature provided by ESP-IDF ISR wrapper code since it's not supported natively by your MCU. But this doesn't really matter.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment above: as the interrupt can come at any time, all the code has to be prepared for the things updated by the isr to change at any time in the middle of any piece of code. And you can't do locking, put the isr to sleep and wait for the interrupted code to let go of the lock so you can do the update. So your updates better be atomic. There are ways to do this, but they are somewhat painful to get right and you should probably minimize the amount of variables that you are going to update this way.

Comment: @dratenik how does this apply to changing the state of objects in particular compared to changing any state inside of an ISR?

Comment: `what should one be aware of when doing it?` Is a too broad question. You should be aware of everything...

Comment: Objects don't add anything special over updating any other piece of data.

Comment: So you are calling some manner of interrupt driver library that lies between your code and the bare metal?

Comment: @Lundin yes, esp-idf to be specific

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything wrong with passing “this” as an argument to ISR registration?

No.

> Is there anything inherently wrong with it?

No.

> If not, what should one be aware of when doing it?

Object lifetime. Compiler optimization. Resource sharing. Locking. Atomic access. Specific hardware semantics. Additionally, esp32 is a two core platform. The list could go on and there are many books about programming on esp32, about programming in parallel environments and sharing resources between main part of code and interrupt routines. One should be aware of all such programming related topics and also about good code conventions, naming and C++ language.

Comment: Am I correct thinking that with "Compiler optimization" you hint at the correct use of "volatile"?

Comment: Well, what `volatile` does it literally disables compiler optimization. But there is also instruction reordering and `std::atomic` and `std::memory_order` and barriers, in case you _want_ to use compiler optimization, instead of using `volatile`.

Comment: any book you'd recommend on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

> I can simply delegate the work from the ISR to the specific object (a resource in this case), managing the resource properties and functionality directly from the class.

This is already wrong. In case you do write a driver in the form of a class for a particular hardware peripheral, then the ISR should be inside that class as a static member function. Or at very least reside in the same translation unit as a `static` function, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a class to begin with.

If you design the program like that though, then sure you can pass a reference to that class.

> Is there anything inherently wrong with it?

Apart from the above, then yeah this must be a singleton object with static storage duration. And using static storage duration objects of C++ classes is inherently wrong in embedded systems, because these will be called by the CRT during microcontroller start-up. Which in turn causes all such C++ programs to start slower than the C equivalent.

But also in this particular case, if the interrupt needs to be started in a timely fashion from the point of power-on reset, then C++ object initialization will not provide that necessary real-time performance. This makes C++ classes unsuitable for interrupts like watchdogs, low-voltage warnings, clock monitor, CPU exceptions and other critical hardware interrupts.

> If not, what should one be aware of when doing it?

The usual re-entrancy problems that appears when you communicate between an ISR and the caller program. This re-entrancy mechanism can be encapsulated in the class.

And as usual, the variables involved in this may need to be `volatile` qualified to prevent incorrect compiler optimizations, depending on how dumb your compiler is. This has nothing to do with re-entrancy. See [Using volatile in embedded C development](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102).

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. Maybe I was a bit unclear, the ISR is static in the translation unit where the class itself also lies. I'll put it static in the class itself instead. (1) However I can't see how making the ISR a static non-member would defeat the purpose of the class, as we can still have RAII for example.

(2) Why do we need it to have static storage duration? Can't I pass a pointer to an object on the stack if I make sure the ISR is unregistered when the object dies?

Comment: @Skusku 1) Because the only purpose of using a class in this case, is the private encapsulation and to store variables shared with the ISR as private. If you can't do that, then C++ only adds useless bloat and you should have coded this part in C. 2) Because in 99% of all applications it doesn't make sense to add and remove ISRs on the fly. And because it needs to be a singleton implementation.

Comment: Also RAII doesn't add anything in the context of low level ISR communication.

Comment: I take the 99% point but I don't think it always needs to be a singleton. Let's take something like software SPI that uses timers. The cstr can setup the timer and register timer interrupts, the dstr can uninstall and unregister them (RAII). If I pass the timer and gpios used to the cstr, I can have multiple software SPIs using different timers and gpios.

Comment: @Skusku You need as many timers as needed for the worst case scenario. No more, no less. If you don't have that many timers simultaneously, then your program won't work. And for that same reason, it rarely ever makes sense for an embedded system to "unregister" timers or "free resources".